# Showing error on parsing api response to model

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am getting the response from the api but after that json decoding error is coming up. It is showing that List is not type of string

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_try/country_model.dart';


class DioClient {
final Dio dio = Dio();
static const baseUrl = 'some Url';

  Future<CountryListModel> fetchPost() async {
   try {
   dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
   dio.options.headers['fcm_token'] = 'test';
   final response = await dio.post(baseUrl);
  print(response.toString());
  return CountryListModel.fromJson(response.data);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e.message + e.error);
  throw Exception(e.message + e.error);
}
}
}
```

Error image[image: Here]

json response

```
[ 
   { 
     "countryCode": "ALB", 
     "countryName": "ALBANIA", 
     "TypeId": "3", 
     "eligible": "Y" 
   },
]
```

Model Class

```
 import 'dart:convert';

 List<CountryListModel> countryListModelFromJson(String str) =>
List<CountryListModel>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => CountryListModel.fromJson(x)));

 String countryListModelToJson(List<CountryListModel> data) =>
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class CountryListModel {
  CountryListModel({
  required this.countryCode,
required this.countryName,
required this.TypeId,
required this.eligible,
 });

 String countryCode;
 String countryName;
 String TypeId;
String eligible;

factory CountryListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  CountryListModel(
    countryCode: json["countryCode"],
    countryName: json["countryName"],
    TypeId: json["TypeId"],
    eligible: json["eligible"],
  );

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "countryCode": countryCode,
    "countryName": countryName,
    "TypeId": TypeId,
    "eligible": eligible,
  };

static List<CountryListModel> countryListModelFromJson(List<dynamic> list) =>
  List<CountryListModel>.from(
      list.map((x) => CountryListModel.fromJson(x)));
  }
```

Comment: Print the `response.data` and attach in question

Comment: [
    {
        "countryCode": "ALB",
        "countryName": "ALBANIA",
        "TypeId": "3",
        "eligible": "Y"
    },]

Comment: It's great, Then share the `CountryListModel` code.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

ِYour api response is `List` and your model class receive `Map` so change your `fetchPost` to this:

```
Future<List<CountryListModel>> fetchPost() async {
      try {
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['fcm_token'] = 'test';
        final response = await dio.post(baseUrl);
        print(response.toString());
        
        return (response.data as List).map((e) => CountryListModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } on DioError catch (e) {
        print(e.message + e.error);
        throw Exception(e.message + e.error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Function `fetchPost()` return type is `CountryListModel`. This code returns `List<CountryListModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function return type to `List<CountryListModel>` and use the method `countryListModelFromJson` in your `CountryListModel` model.

```dart
Future<List<CountryListModel>> fetchPost() async {
      try {
        dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        dio.options.headers['fcm_token'] = 'test';
        final response = await dio.post(baseUrl);
        print(response.toString());
        
        return CountryListModel.countryListModelFromJson(response.data);
      } on DioError catch (e) {
        print(e.message + e.error);
        throw Exception(e.message + e.error);
      }
    }
```